# Creating ssh keys on remote hosts using ansible fails

Tags: ssh, yaml, ansible, pexpect

I am using Ansible to create ssh keys on remote hosts. Following is the playbook code

```
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: all
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - name: Create ssh keys
      expect:
        command: ssh-keygen -t rsa
        echo: yes
        timeout: 5
        responses:
          "file": "" ## Enter file in which to save the key (/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa)
          "Overwrite": "n" ## Overwrite (y/n)? 
          "passphrase": "" ## Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase)
```

However, it get the following error:

> fatal: [10.1.1.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ssh-keygen -t rsa", "delta": "0:00:00.301769", "end": "2015-12-30 09:56:29.465815", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"chdir": null, "command": "ssh-keygen -t rsa", "creates": null, "echo": true, "removes": null, "responses": {"Overwrite": "n", "file": "", "passphrase": ""}, "timeout": 5}, "module_name": "expect"}, "rc": 1, "start": "2015-12-30 09:56:29.164046", "stdout": "Generating public/private rsa key pair.\r\nEnter file in which to save the key (/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa): \r\n/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.\r\nOverwrite (y/n)? n", "stdout_lines": ["Generating public/private rsa key pair.", "Enter file in which to save the key (/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa): ", "/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.", "Overwrite (y/n)? n"]}

This does work fine when "Overwrite" is mapped to "y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does work fine when "Overwrite" is mapped to "y".

If that's the case then it sounds like your task is working properly.  `ssh-keygen` will only prompt to overwrite the file if it already exists, and your response to "Overwrite" in the task is "n".  If you tell ssh-keygen to not overwrite the file then it will exit immediately with a non-zero return code, which Ansible interprets as an error.

If you only want this task to execute when the key doesn't exist (in order to create a new key but not overwrite an existing one) then you probably want to add the following to your task:

```
creates: /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The `creates` modifier will prevent the task from executing if the specified file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following, to create keys for a specific user with the right access rights:

```
- name: Create ssh key
  shell: |
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f /home/{{ ansible_user }}/.ssh/id_ed25519 -C {{ ansible_user }}@{{ inventory_hostname }}
    chown {{ ansible_user }}:{{ ansible_user }} /home/{{ ansible_user }}/.ssh/id_ed25519*
  args:
    creates: '/home/{{ ansible_user }}/.ssh/id_ed25519'
```